# What is the difference between どの+noun+も vs 毎+noun for “Every (noun)”?

Tags: usage, nuances, adverbs

In which cases is it more appropriate to use どの+noun+も instead of 毎+noun (or vice versa)

Comment: Can you give an example sentence where you think they might be interchangeable?

Comment: 毎 is not so productive as you may be thinking. It’s not like it goes with any noun naturally.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

どの can be a translation of "every" or "any" in a lot of cases. Example:

- **どの**席も空いている。 (**Every/any** seat is empty/available.)

毎 for a similar meaning is typically a prefix to form a larger word. It's generally not productive, and the word often has to do with time. Example:

- 彼は**毎日**出勤する。 (He comes to work **everyday**.)
- 彼は**毎回**失敗する。 (He fails **every time**.)